# run migrations in parallel django?

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing, django-migrations

The current project has around 620 django models, which takes around 1 hour to migrate. . (uses only 12.x% of 8 core intel skylake with 1.2gigs of 30gigs ram on gcloud while migration) this metrics is combined for pg and python 2 (cpython). I assume that only a single core is used while migrating. [celery processes uses 100% CPU + 50% of ram. ]

each migration is like,

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('dist', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='model name',
            fields=[
                ...
                ...
                60 fields
                ...
                ...
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

they are identical but with some minor changes to fields.

Is there any way to migrate this database faster? can I run migrations on parallel? since migrations after 30 (internal apps and dists) are not related to each other, can I run these migrations in parallel?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, migrations are (for good reasons) designed to be applied sequentially (consider for example a scenario where one migration creates a model and another modifies it - running them in parallel could make Django try to modify a model that does not exist yet). In your case squashing the migrations could speed things up - to quote documentation:

> Squashing is the act of reducing an existing set of many migrations down to one (or sometimes a few) migrations which still represent the same changes.
>
> Django does this by taking all of your existing migrations, extracting their **Operation**s and putting them all in sequence, and then running an optimizer over them to try and reduce the length of the list - for example, it knows that **CreateModel** and **DeleteModel** cancel each other out, and it knows that **AddField** can be rolled into **CreateModel**.
>
> Once the operation sequence has been reduced as much as possible - the amount possible depends on how closely intertwined your models are and if you have any **RunSQL** or **RunPython** operations (which can’t be optimized through unless they are marked as **elidable**) - Django will then write it back out into a new set of migration files.

Read more about squashing migrations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations).

Comment: I said the migration after the first 30s are identical and independent of each other. If I break a migration process, I can continue back from where I left off, so does it makes some sense to apply them in parallell?

Comment: They **do** depend on each other - look at the `dependencies` field in the `Migration` class. Because of the way the system is designed there is no bulit-in method to apply migrations in parallel - you would have to write such a method yourself, most probably breaking the migration system in the process.